# Selecionar option em select de outra maneira com AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

Recentemente encontrei [esse exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/gFCzV/34/) no JSFiddle para selecionar determinado `option` em um elemento `select`.

Reparei que é selecionado da seguinte maneira:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="listitem" ng-repeat="Choice in Person.Choices">
     {{Choice.Name}}: 
     <select 
        ng-model="Choice.SelectedOption"                 
        ng-options="choice.Name for choice in Choice.Options track by choice.ID"></select>
    {{Choice.SelectedOption.ID}}
</div>
```

**JSON**:

```
{
 "Name":"Dinner",
 "Options":[{Name:"Fish",ID:1}, {Name:"Chicken",ID:2}, {Name:"Beef",ID:3}],
 "SelectedOption":{Name:"Chicken",ID:2} // Neste trecho
}
```

**Dúvida**:

Não posso criar uma variável global dentro da minha controladora dessa maneira:

```
$scope.selected;
```

E colocar o valor de `ng-model` do elemento `select` com `selected` e passar o valor do ID que eu quero simplesmente sem fazer da forma que esta fazendo? Ou seja, passando o valor do `option` que eu quero invés de um objeto JSON.

Existem outras maneiras?

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi corretamente, sim - apenas altere

```
ng-model="Choice.SelectedOption"
```

para

```
ng-model="selected"
```

e a diretiva utilizará *$scope.selected* como o aspecto do modelo a sofrer *binding*.

Comment: Estava fazendo exatamente como você falou @Ibotinelly, estou utilizando o AngularJS 1.5, porém ao passar apenas o `oid`(identificador) para o aspectro do modelo o `select` não sofria alteração. Porém quando passei o objeto inteiro, com o `oid` e a `descricao` contidos no `ng-options`, funcionou corretamente. `$scope.objeto.oid = 1` e `$scope.objeto.descricao = "valor"`.